# how to deploy an ecs service with a task definition that has 2 images with blue green deployment?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I had configured CodePipeline with CodeBuild and ECS blue green as an action provider to deploy my ECS service. In my buildspec.yml I created imageDetail.json like this {"ImageURI": "imageid"}. This setup was working fine when my task definition had only one image.

Now my task definition has two images where one image depends from the other so I changed my buildspec.yml to create an imageDetail.json like this:

[{"ImageURI":"image1"}, {"ImageURI":"image2"}]

When configuring the pipeline with codebuild and ECS blue green deploy with this new task definition and imageDetail.json that has 2 images it is throwing the following error: "**Exception while trying to parse the image URI file from the artifact: BuildArtifact.**"

Then I tried doing this same setup but with ECS (rolling update) as an action provider instead of ECS blue green and it worked. With ECS (rolling update) as an action provider I needed to create an imagedefinitions.json instead of an imageDetail.json. The imagedefinitions.json created in buildspec.yml looks like this:

```
[{"name":"name1","imageUri":"image1"}, {"name":"name2","imageUri":"image2"}]
```

However, I want to use ECS blue green as an action provider where I need to create an imageDetail.json in the buildspec.yml file. So, can I create an imageDetail.json with two images like in imagedefinitions.json?

Comment: did you figure out it ?